# Installing Large Flick board on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi4

I recently purchased a Flick Large board for my Raspberry Pi 4B and am having issues getting it working. I believe I have everything set up correctly when comparing it to the quick start guide and following the steps on github with no success. Below are my steps that I followed and the error I am getting when running the flick-demo:

1. Set up Pins:

   - LED2-Pin15
   - LED1-Pin7
   - GND-Pin9
   - TS-Pin13
   - Reset-Pin11
   - I2C SCL-Pin5
   - I2C SDA-Pin3
   - 3v3-Pin1
2. ran curl-sSl [https://pisupp.ly/flickcode |](https://pisupp.ly/flickcode%C2%A0%7C) sudo bash
3. Then verified connection with i2cdetect -y 1 - Output below

   ```
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f
   ```

   00:                         -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --

   10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --

   20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --

   30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --

   40: -- -- 42 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --

   50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --

   60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
4. Tried to run the sudo apt-get install wiringpi; but received the error that it was no longer being supported. Found the following work around

   - cd /tmp
   - wget https://project-downloads.drogon.net/wiringpi-latest.deb
   - sudo dpkg -i wiringpi-latest.deb
5. Re-ran sudo apt-get install wiringpi to confirm installed and latest version (2.52)
6. Set the GPIO 17 as instructed with:

   - gpio mode 0 out; gpio write 0 0; gpio write 0 1; i2cdetect -y 1
7. From here I confirmed I could turn the LED's on and off in BASH with:

   - gpio -g mode 22 out
   - gpio -g mode 22 1
8. Then I attempted to run flick-demo - received the error below:

   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/usr/local/bin/flick-demo", line 4, in 
       **import**('pkg_resources').run_script('flicklib==0.0.3', 'flick-demo')
     File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 651, in run_script
       self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
     File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 1455, in run_script
       exec(script_code, namespace, namespace)
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/flicklib-0.0.3-py3.9.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/flick-demo", line 4, in 
       **import**('pkg_resources').run_script('flicklib==0.0.3', 'flick-demo')
     File "", line 1007, in _find_and_load
     File "", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
     File "", line 664, in _load_unlocked
     File "", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
     File "", line 259, in load_module
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/flicklib-0.0.3-py3.9.egg/flicklib.py", line 508, in 
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/flicklib-0.0.3-py3.9.egg/flicklib.py", line 330, in _start_poll
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/flicklib-0.0.3-py3.9.egg/flicklib.py", line 103, in start
   AttributeError: 'AsyncWorker' object has no attribute 'isAlive'
9. I thought I missed a step; so i opened the install.sh file I found:

   - apt-get install -y git whiptail

     - It was already installed
   - then I ran:

     - raspi-config nonint do_i2c 0
     - git clone https://github.com/PiSupply/Flick.git
     - cd Flick/flick
     - python setup.py install
     - reboot
10. Then I tried to re-run the flick-demo and received the same error as before.

This is all done on a new install of Rasberry Pi OS (32-bit) released 2021-10-30. I ensure to run apt-get updates and upgrades and came back with fully updated before beginning my install.

I am stumped on what I am doing wrong. I am hoping someone can help point me in the right direction.

My end goal hopefully use the flick to replace a mouse on the Raspberry Pi.

Thank you for any assistance!